# keeping track of threads accessing files, with and without Queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I noticed some behavior when using threads and Queues that I'm having a hard time understanding. I spent a good bit of time scouring google and still haven't found an explanation that I understand, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have a function like this...

```
# it doesn't really matter what the path is, so let's just refer to 
# it as 'base_path'
def stat_somedir(base_path):

    stat_profile = cProfile.Profile()
    stat_profile.enable()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        for file_ in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(base_path, file_)
            if not os.path.isfile(file_path): continue

    stat_profile.disable()
    stat_profile.print_stats(sort='time')
```

When I run the function by simply calling stat_somedir(base_path), this is the first line of the profiler's output. It spent most of its time in posix.stat...

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1610    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000    {posix.stat}
```

Next, I run the function inside a thread, here's the code...

```
class StatThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        stat_somedir()

# initially, I thought having multiple threads might be the culprit
# so the code is structured that way, but we'll only use one thread
# in this example
thread_one = StatThread()
waiting_threads = [thread_one]
running_threads = []

for thread in waiting_threads:
    running_threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

done_threads = []
while running_threads:
    for thread in running_threads:
        # This is commented out on purpose, it will matter later.
        #time.sleep(1)
        if thread.isAlive():
            continue
        else:
            running_threads.remove(thread)
            done_threads.append(thread)
```

The first line of the profiler's output is...

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1610    3.387    0.002    3.387    0.002    {posix.stat}
```

Clearly, the time spent in posix.stat has gone waaay up. If I comment out the sleep line, the first line of output becomes...

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1610    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000    {posix.stat}
```

This is much closer to the time spent when running stat_somedir() outside of a thread.

I also tried using a Queue, here's the code...

```
def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        stat_somedir()
        q.task_done()

q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=1)

worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
worker.setDaemon(True)
worker.start()

for x in range(1):
    q.put(x)

q.join()
```

and again, here's the first line of profiler output. This is basically equivalent to running stat_somedir() outside a thread or running it with a thread and using time.sleep()..

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1610    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000    {posix.stat}
```

I actually have a couple questions...

1. Why does adding time.sleep(1) while checking the threads make stat_somedir() run so much faster? I assume it has something to do with thread.isAlive blocking the thread from running os.path.isfile, but I don't know for sure and I can't explain why. (I made another version which, instead of os.path.isfile, simply printed out numbers, but having time.sleep made no difference there; the code ran equally fast outside the thread, inside thread, and in a Queue. That's why I figure something about file access is the explanation...)
2. Why does running this code in a Queue have the same effect on the time spent doing posix.stat that adding time.sleep(1) has? What is Queue doing "under the hood"?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The profiler is sort of lying to you.  Here's why:

In the case where you have no `sleep()`, when you make a system call to do I/O, the running thread is put to sleep until the I/O completes.  Meanwhile your main thread (the one with the `while` loop) spins in a tight Python loop.  While it spins it holds the Python Global Interpreter Lock.  This means that even when the I/O completes, no Python code can run in `StatThread` because the GIL cannot be acquired.

Given all this, I'm not sure it's guaranteed that your program will ever complete--it could result in a "livelock" depending on the interpreter implementation.  But it does eventually complete, perhaps because there is some time quantum which elapses and makes Python decide to stop running the main spin loop and try running code in `StatThread` instead.

In any case, `cProfile` doesn't know that `posix.stat` is starved of execution time, it only knows that from the time it started until the time it finished was a long time.  It doesn't subtract the time spent waiting for the GIL.

By the way, you can make the `sleep()` really really short if you want, it will "solve" the problem just as well as sleeping for a full second.  But better would be to just `join()` the thread(s) and avoid burning CPU cycles for nothing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, this is making a lot more sense now! It does eventually complete, at least on my machine. If StatThread was not making any system calls, would that negate the need for sleep()? It seemed to be the case in the tests I ran; is this because when StatThread is purely Python code, Python knows what should have the GIL and doesn't end up spinning in a tight loop?

Comment: Basically yes, because if you have two threads running Python code that is CPU bound and therefore not releasing the GIL, you need to give both of them plenty of CPU time, so it doesn't matter so much what the granularity is of switching between the two tasks you can run.  But note that in such cases threading brings little or no benefit, because you can't use more than a single CPU worth of time with pure Python code (with the regular interpreter anyway).